# Rails submit different fields to different controllers in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webforms

I have a form setup and want it so that:

name, address (and other address details) submit to my **BillingAddress**

While

credit_card_number etc would submit to **PaymentMethod**

I'm using things such as **f.text_field** for my form fields.

But, my payment method has a **billing_address_id**, so I would like it to submit the specified data to BillingAddress, create that new instance, then assign its id to PaymentMethod while also submitting that other data to PaymentMethod.

**Sidenote**:
I understand I should save credit card numbers in the db, I will use a gem later on to handle holding this data properly, but for now, I just want to get the basic structure down.

Comment: is there any association between BillingAddress and PaymentMethod?

Comment: Yes, as I said, a PaymentMethod has a billing_address_id, it has a billing address.

Answer (score 1):

use this while creating BillingAddress

```
@billing_address = BillingAddress.create(params[:billingaddress])
@billing_address.payment_method.create(payment_method_params)
```

Comment: Ah ok, so only submit to one controller, but do this for each stack/level of models?   I guess the other thing is, using f.text_field or whatever tag, if I use a method from a different controller, errors occur.

Comment: @FengHuo can you please add your code in question? so I'll provide you  detailed answer.